# Can references provided for each section and without any copy/paste text still be labeled as plagiarized?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, plagiarism

This question is in reference to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56474438/whats-the-difference-between-driver-execute-script-and-driver-getja/56604956?noredirect=1#comment99800439_56604956) for the question *[What's the difference between `driver.execute_script("...")` and `driver.get("javascript: ..."` with geckodriver/Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56474438/whats-the-difference-between-driver-execute-script-and-driver-getja)* which is pretty much a beginner/basic question.

I have constructed an answer detailing out the basic concepts in six sections (including the *Conclusion* section). Each section includes an implicit reference to the relevant documentation. I am pretty sure there is **no presence of copy/paste text** and each sentence was as per my understanding about the subject matter. For example:

- `Window Object`: This section has implicit reference to `https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp`
- `window.location`: This section starts with the phrase `As per the documentation` and has implicit reference to `https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp`
- `window.location.href`: This section has implicit reference to `https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script`
- `get(url)`: Has implicit reference to `https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get`

I understand that the text present within the documentation is pretty terse and when someone needs to speak on those topics, a majority of the technical terms/phrases can sound as plagiarized.

Can I have any suggestions about the additional steps I should take to avoid getting labeled as plagiarized?

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything that looks like obvious plagiarism, but I also don't think that you are answering the question. At least your conclusion doesn't look like a comparison of `get` and `execute_script`. In the text above, I also don't see any such comparison in the rest of your answer. You might want to flag your post for moderator attention and ask which parts they assume to be plagiarized.

Comment: @BDL see duplode answer to get an highlight on the plagiarism.

Comment: You had one paragraph that was a copy and paste, the rest was ok. I checked the entire answer, it had a custom flag on it and you'd been pulled up for this before. You are a good contributor, it's just a matter of ironing out how to reference other's work and what constitutes plagiarism.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Thanks for the clarification. 1) Though I would agree with your comment (at duplode answer) _"one paragraph that was close to a copy paste"_ but allow me to disagree with _"one paragraph that was a copy and paste"_. Considering the low volume of text within the documentation and numerous answerer referring to the same words/phrases are bound to sound similar either from this site or the other. 2) _custom flag_: That's the way contributors seeks moderators attention referring either NAA/VLQ/plagiarized. The final call is always with you to mark if the flag is justified or not.

Comment: @DebanjanB I understand the difficulty re small amount of text. However plagiarism is a tricky area and it's always better to err on the side of caution. I work as an academic and mark papers and caution students of the same thing.

Comment: -1 for quoting W3Schools ( this should be automatic )

Comment: Personally I very often directly quote text. Of course the quoted text is in >quotes and the source right after. I would personally say that it sometimes is better to quote someone rather than attempt to interpret because often what we think is what something is saying is really far from it. Directly quoting someone and then providing your interpretation is better for the reader to know where what you're saying is coming from and whether or not your interpretation was helpful or just wrong.

Answer (score 11):

The "Window Object" section of your answer is a very [close paraphrasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Close_paraphrasing) of the W3Schools page you link to; as such, it requires attribution. While you describe it as having an "implicit reference", I'd say that implicit *attribution* isn't really a thing. It isn't obvious to someone who comes across your answer that that section was taken almost word by word from the source -- to discover that, one would have to follow the link and find the matching section there. In such cases, it is better to, depending on what works best in the context of your answer, either write a new text that conveys the same ideas without being a paraphrasis of the source, or include a clearly delimited quotation of the original text with explicit attribution. In this case, the latter option might look like this:

---

As [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp) puts it:

> The `window` object is supported by all browsers. It represents the
>   browser's window.
>
> All global JavaScript objects, functions, and variables automatically
>   become members of the window object.
>
> Global variables are properties of the window object.
>
> Global functions are methods of the window object.

[At this point, you'd probably want to add a few more words highlighting why the quoted text is relevant for your answer.]

Comment: Yes there was one paragraph that was close to a copy paste and that's why I deleted it with a message about plagiarism. Work has to be paraphrased and in different words otherwise it needs to be quoted. Thanks for this answer.