# Why is this well-explained answer with 50+ upvotes deleted?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers, moderation, community-moderation

Consider this deleted answer:

[image: Answer part 1]

[image: Answer part 2]

My answer for question *[Delete a file or folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/delete-a-file-or-folder/39079453#39079453)* is deleted by a moderator. I don't understand under which cause it comes for deleting this answer.

Answers can be deleted if

- commentary on the question or other answers - NA
- asking another, different question - NA
- “thanks!” or “me too!” responses - NA
- exact duplicates of other answers - I don't think it is duplicate. It have well explained what are different ways of doing things. Can anyone point out which of which answer it is duplicate?
- barely more than a link to an external site - NA
- not even a partial answer to the actual question - NA

Am I eligible to know the root cause for deleting answer?

Comment: The moderator always adds a comment stating the reason for deletion

Comment: @Lighteninger: Comments not added.

Comment: by any chance, was it a simple copy from the official Doc? it seems so and it's a valid reason for deletion

Comment: There was no comment by Yvette about the deletion?

Comment: @yivi there was no comment

Comment: @TemaniAfif: No it is not a copy of official doc

Comment: well, I am comparing and it's copy/paste for me ... I don't know python but I am reading almost the same sentences

Comment: *os.removedirs(name) Remove directories recursively. Works like rmdir() except that, if the leaf directory is successfully removed, removedirs() tries to successively remove every parent directory mentioned in path until an error is raised (which is ignored, because it generally means that a parent directory is not empty).

For example, os.removedirs('foo/bar/baz') will first remove the directory 'foo/bar/baz', and then remove 'foo/bar' and 'foo' if they are empty.* --> the same on your answer and the DOC

Comment: @TemaniAfif: But that's what it meant. Description might be some plain english that explains well in 2 sentences. It can be changed if needs to be rewritten. But that can't be reason to delete? is it so? Whole answer is not a copy from some source. Some sentences can always come from some source.

Comment: You need to be more explicit when you are quoting material. You are linking to the original, but it's not evident what's a quote and what not. Fix that, and you could re-flag for undeletion.

Comment: if you simply *copy* an existing text without your own contribution then it should be a comment with a link to that source and yes it's valid to delete. I would flag such answer if I saw it. We should cearly see *your* answer.

Comment: If you copy something from somewhere else you need to at least mention that in your answer clearly so that people know where you got your information from and to show that you are not trying to plagiarize. I can't see anything like that in the screenshots. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64966/7443472) for example on how to do that. Explicitly mention what is copied and what is yours, use citation markdown, link to the site where you found the original, ...

Comment: I've tried to edit your answer for formatting on what I was pretty sure was the doc source, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing as well as it explain why this may happen when a lot of a post appears in other sites "verbatim"

Comment: I had already given links to Official doc what I was referring to for each title. Still not added official  doc link as source that I have done now. With link need some info to have some understanding. Is it eligible for undelete or do I need to modify/rewrite text and meaning of answer? @TemaniAfif

Comment: OK got you.. @Tensibai.. It should look like it is referred content.

Comment: as @Secespitus said, we need to be able to identify your own text from the one you took from the DOC. A simple reader will say that you are simply copying existing text from another source and this is not valid.

Comment: I can not flag for undelete this answer now. It says "A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted" @yivi

Comment: Are you "flagging", or just trying to vote to undelete? You need to raise a custom mod flag, explaining the situation and the actions you took to solve it.

Comment: Related: [*Can references provided for each section and without any copy/paste text still be labeled as plagiarized?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386103/2751851)

Comment: @Lighteninger Most moderators (unfortunately) don't leave comments on deleted posts to answer the *why*. And it seems some moderators willy-nilly delete answers, even very high-scored ones (but as they don't leave comments it is difficult to tell if it is *really* willy-nilly).

Comment: (In whatever way the system allows it - the information may have to be added to the post itself.)

Comment: We also require that answers are at least *mostly* your own work. Referencing work by 3rd parties is fine, but it can only be used sparingly *to support your own answer*. If all your answer does is copy some external source, then even if properly quoted and attributed, then you still didn't actually create any of that answer and no value was created by you. So *don't just copy and quote*. Write answers in your own words and use external sources to help underpin your answer, at most.

Comment: When you posted that answer, all you had done was copy documentation into the answer box. So I'd certainly dispute the claim that this answer was 'well-explained'. Nothing new was added that wasn't already in the documentation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, how much is mostly and on what reference ? If not counting output text, I think [this answer of me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31567731/3627607) could be a bit borderline on a word count basis (while I think I fairly understand what is meant, I think more details may help newcomers better understand it)

Comment: @Tensibai: you are clearly using referenced documentation to support your answer. If you removed the quoted section your answer might be a bit poorer, but still would answer the question. You clearly did not rely on the authors of the referenced documentation to do the answering for you. Ergo, it is not plagiarism.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : Thanks. Understood now. Those were old answers. Information can be understood by that content. I have given references most of the time. It was not like stealing content and copyright issues. Don't know why you are deleting my many answers now. Contents can be edited if you want. Deletion was not the solution to it. People were upvoting those answers means were getting some value. I could have improved those. Many were in top answers to those questions. I am feeling like being targeted.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: deletion does not preclude you from editing the posts. If you can recover the answer by properly attributing the content and ensuring that there is enough material of your own in the answer, you can flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: note that we have also deleted answers that were just copies of your own answers, where the question should have been closed as a duplicate instead. Those were given a different comment to help you understand why that was done.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk And to complete, yes when we (users or mods) come to find something wich is plagiarism (not citing source, not properly formatted), the [expected behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered) is to search for more from the same user as it's often a pattern.

Comment: I will try to edit those answers when I get time and try to recover them. Thanks for educating. @MartijnPieters

Comment: @PeterMortensen the post flags are retained and visible to moderators and the community managers. In this specific case the post was flagged by a community member to point out the copying. When I leave a comment whilst cleaning up plagiarism cases I do so to document the source, not really to communicate with the author, and may not even do that if an existing flag already served that purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry I didn't see this. I'd like people to feel free to ping me on the site when there's an action I've taken.

---

I deleted your post.

I responded to this post flag.

[image]

Please see:

### [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

> .../...
>
> Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their
>   words and ideas to support your own. And always give proper credit to
>   the author and site where you found the text, including a direct link
>   to it.
>
> .../...

Often when the moderators find plagiarised or unoriginal content that is highly upvoted we will ask the community managers to dissociate the post, so that the reputation is removed. We have strict plagiarism guidelines and follow U.S. copyright law (<--- I need a legal eagle to validate that last point). I'm acutely aware that we are a global community and not everyone understands or abides by these laws, so it's important to try and teach people first.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk you are welcome. Feel free to draw my attention to any posts on here you think I may be able to answer.

Comment: I have rewritten content manually and I hope this should be undeleted. Let me know if current content sounds good.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk would you be ok to raise a custom mod flag on the answer? I'm about to go to bed and I don't want to forget it

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: the post has since been disassociated from your account, a standard practice to clear reputation gained from content not the poster's own for posts older than 60 days and with a score of 3 or more (where reputation gain is otherwise not removed when a post is deleted).

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: So **at this point** there is no use in undeleting that post, it is no longer yours. You may as well post a new answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : That's not fair :(

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: Sorry you feel that that's not fair. But gaining reputation from works by other people is also not fair, not when everyone else writes their own answers. If you can gain reputation from just copying content, why bother writing answers yourself?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: and if we *didn't* remove the reputation gained, and only deleted posts, then there is still an incentive for someone to copy content and hope it stays undetected for long enough and gains enough upvotes for the reputation to 'stick' when eventually the plagiarism is detected and deleted. That would also not be fair, and people will keep using plagiarism to gain reputation rather than accept that that's not how things work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : Sorry. I am saying not fair by not to have option to undelete and associate again. If I am investing my some time again to correct my mistakes which were not prominent to me at time of writing answer. There should be some time period before disassociating and it must be known to author of answer which I wasn't aware if that's the case. Or you should disable edit option. Isn't that bad that even getting readers of site benefit from answer and now there is no revival can be done. There is thin line between moderation and giving time for community.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: the votes on your answer were based on the content that was there at the time. That content was not your own, and so the reputation gain should rightly have been removed. We all have spent time learning what is right and what isn't on this site, it is moderation that keeps this fair for everyone. Note that *I volunteer my time too*, and that finding and cleaning up plagiarism is a considerable time sink.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : Agreed. Thanks :) I will be adding another answer.